# How to optimize the performance of a table without any primary keys, unique keys or foreign keys?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

I have a table that saves the GPS position of multiple vehicles on one day. So it's has multiple IDs, some info about location, some other info, and date (timestamp date+time).

DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME;

```
    DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME;

    Name        Null     Type           
    ----------- -------- -------------- 
    ID_1        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    ID_2        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)   
    ID_3        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)   
    ID_4        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)   
    INFO_1      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    LAT         NOT NULL FLOAT(126)     
    LNG         NOT NULL FLOAT(126)     
    DATE        NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)   
    INFO_2      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    INFO_3      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    INFO_4      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    INFO_5      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    INFO_6      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    INFO_7      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
    TEXTMSG              VARCHAR2(4000)
```

So, I have to run the same query indicating different TIMEs like this:

```
    SELECT 
    to_char(ID_1) as ID_1,
    ID_2,
    ID_4,
    to_char(INFO_1) as INFO_1,
    substr(LAT, 1, 32767) as LAT,
    substr(LNG, 1, 32767) as LNG,
    to_char(DATE,'dd/MM/yy HH24:MI:SS') as DATE,
    to_char(INFO_2) as INFO_2,
    to_char(INFO_3) as INFO_3,
    to_char(INFO_4) as INFO_4,
    to_char(INFO_5) as INFO_5,
    to_char(INFO_6) as INFO_6,
    to_char(INFO_7) as INFO_7,
    TEXTMSG 
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE to_char(DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') = '09:10:25';
```

This query always take about 25 seconds.
There is about 1 millions records on the table.

Is it normal the time that it takes (25 seconds)?
How can improve this time?

I tried to do an index like the following but nothing changed:

```
CREATE INDEX INDEX_TABLE_NAME ON TABLE_NAME (DATE);
```

Note: I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.1.0 64bit (on Windows, just for testing purposes)

Comment: Reasoning about the number of seconds it took may not be the best approach, depending on too many things; it would be useful if you could post the explain plan of both queries ( with and without index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want want to speed the query, then use an expression index:

```
create index idx_tablename_exp on table_name(to_char(DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Then, Oracle will be able to use this index for your `where` clause.